# MySql returns not correct AVG

Tags: mysql, sql, average

**Table:**

```
Column               |       Type
-------------------------------------------
Project_ID           |       INT AI
-------------------------------------------
Rejection_Rate       |       double
-------------------------------------------
```

**Data:**

```
Proj Name                 |       AVG Value
-------------------------------------------
Project1                  |         100
-------------------------------------------
Project2                  |         200
-------------------------------------------
Project2                  |         100
-------------------------------------------
```

**MySql Query:**

```
SELECT concat(Project_ID,'-',Project_Name) as `Proj Name`,
ROUND(Avg(Rejection_Rate),2) as `AVG Value`
FROM project
GROUP BY Project_ID
ORDER BY Project_ID
```

**RESULT:**

```
Proj Name                 |       AVG Value
-------------------------------------------
Project1                  |         100.00
-------------------------------------------
Project2                  |         135.77
-------------------------------------------
```

Above are the actual data.

The return value on AVG is incorrect. **Project2** returns **135.77**. 
It should be  **150.00** **right?**

**Also, why the result is 135.77?**

I also tried some of the possibilities why I ended up with 135.77 but didn't come up the same result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/034b1/1

Comment: Pls explain pls why downvoted? I really don't have any idea what is wrong or did I miss more information to my question?

Comment: In your fiddle you have three values: 100, 200, 107.32. Of course the average is 135.77

Comment: Thank sir @SamiKuhmonen ,.. I miss that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear where `Rejection_Rate` is located in your tables.

Compare with this...

```
CREATE TABLE Nums (
  ProjName VARCHAR(20),
  ProjVal DOUBLE
);

INSERT INTO Nums
VALUES ("A", 100), ("A", 175), ("B", 200), ("B", 100);

SELECT DISTINCT ProjName, Round(Avg(ProjVal),2) Average
FROM Nums
GROUP BY ProjName;
```

Results were 137.5 for project "A" and 150 for project "B"

Comment: Rejection Rate is type double.. I tried to run your example and it works correctly (returns 150.00).  The only difference in your sample is the INT type w/c mine is Double. Does the type makes the difference? 
Why I get 135.77? How it is being computed? thank you!

Comment: Double has to do with precision of the number.  I would switch to `INT` or `FLOAT` types if possible.  I updated my answer with `DOUBLE` and it works.

Comment: Honestly I'm now a bit confused. Changing your Type to Double works seamlessly but our fields/columns are almost identical already but still getting 135.77. I am expecting 150.00 result the same as your example. Could you please explain why I get that result? thanks

Comment: Probably there is an another 'Project 2' in your `SELECT`